# My code will not allow me to put a image into my java code

Tags: java, joptionpane, imageicon

I cannot seem to fix this part of my code, all I am trying to do is add a picture in, I have put it into the Java fills and everything I just do not know what is going on:

```
ImageIcon al = new ImageIcon("Walmart.jpeg");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Come " + verb + " at WALMART, where you'll receive "
     + adjective + " discounts on all of your favorite brand name "
     + nounplursl + ".", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, al, null);
```

Comment: We really need a [mcve] and a description of your problem in order to help you.

Comment: You have described what you’re trying to do, but you have not explained what behavior you are actually seeing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems issue in the parameter that your have used to call showMessageDialog.
Remove the null at the end and pass one more string after message.

```
ImageIcon al = new ImageIcon("Walmart.jpeg");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Come " + verb + " at WALMART, where you'll receive "
     + adjective + " discounts on all of your favorite brand name "
     + nounplursl + ".", "Additional String", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, al);
```

If you still don't see image, try using getResource.

```
ImageIcon al = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Walmart.jpeg"));
```